# jQuery: To print the first object from a set of repeated objects in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array like this:

```
var json.result= [
{"id":"0","category":"Camera","name":"600D Kit", "condition":"OK"},    
{"id":"1","category":"Camera","name":"600D Kit", "condition":"missing cap"},        
{"id":"2","category":"Camera","name":"7D Kit", "condition":"OK"},
{"id":"3","category":"Camera","name":"7D Kit", "condition":"OK"}]
```

I am trying to do the following:
1/ Find all the "name"
2/ When found duplicated "name", print only the first object

So that the result would be:

equipment id: 0

category: Camera

name: 600D Kit

equipment id: 2

category: Camera

name: 7D Kit

The following is my attempt:

```
json.result.map(function(equipment){

    var equipmentNamesArray = equipment.name;
    var arr = $.makeArray(equipmentNamesArray);

    var uniqueNames = equipmentNamesArray.reduce(function(a,b){
        if (a.indexOf(b) < 0) a.push(b);    
    }, equipmentNamesArray);
    console.log("equipment ID: ", uniqueNames.id);
    console.log("category: ", uniqueNames.category);
    console.log("name: ", uniqueNames);     
});
```

However, I have an error of `TypeError: equipmentNamesArray.reduce is not a function`. I would appreciate very much if anyone could tell me which part of the logic have I done wrong please :)))

Cheers,
Karen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/bgzqLvj0/)

```
var json = [], equipmentNamesArray = [];

json.result= [
{"id":"0","category":"Camera","name":"600D Kit", "condition":"OK"},    
{"id":"1","category":"Camera","name":"600D Kit", "condition":"missing cap"},        
{"id":"2","category":"Camera","name":"7D Kit", "condition":"OK"},
{"id":"3","category":"Camera","name":"7D Kit", "condition":"OK"}];

json.result.map(function(equipment) {
    if ($.inArray(equipment.name, equipmentNamesArray) === -1) {
      console.log(equipment);
      equipmentNamesArray.push(equipment.name);
    }
});
```

You have to create the `equipmentNamesArray` array to contain the items checked before everything else, when you start iterate the main `result` array you check if the `equipment.name` is already in the `equipmentNamesArray` array.

If it's not in the array print it and push it to the array.

Then the next one will be skipped because is contained in the `equipmentNamesArray` array yet.

Here is another version with a change to keep a new array with only the items you want: [JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/m8ad140n/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and JSFiddle is exactly what I need :))) Merci beaucoup x